# Установка пакетов npm, ошибка

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

[image: скрин ошибок]

Установил ноду, дальше пошла такая ерунда при установке пакетов npm. Пробовал заново, менял директорию установки

$ npm i
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile

up to date, audited 1087 packages in 13s

111 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: Замените картинку текстом в блоке специального формата. И укажите, пожалуйста, версию Node.js

Comment: Просто предположение, что может вы зря исользуете git bash? для установки npm пакетов. Может воспользоваться cmd или PS???